# Caching framework for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

In the ASP.NET MVC aplication that I am working on, there is a large amount of static data ( there are no update/insert to this table during runtime) which I need to retrieve by either grouping by different columns or summing up and aggreation, The mathematical operations are pretty simple.

Now there are a lot of calls issued to the repository which slows down the controller response. Can you please suggest a good caching framework which allows me to cache the repository calls (with the same input parameters) without writing custom code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Memorycache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) simply suits your case by just adding into your repositories

But remember:

> The MemoryCache class is similar to the ASP.NET Cache class. The MemoryCache class has many properties and methods for accessing the cache that will be familiar to you if you have used the ASP.NET Cache class. The main differences between the Cache and MemoryCache classes are that the MemoryCache class has been changed to make it usable by .NET Framework applications that are not ASP.NET applications. For example, the MemoryCache class has no dependencies on the System.Web assembly. Another difference is that you can create multiple instances of the MemoryCache class for use in the same application and in the same AppDomain instance.

Answer (score 4):

[CacheManager](http://www.cachemanager.net/)

CacheManager is an open source caching framework for .NET written in C# and is available via NuGet. It supports various cache providers and implements many advanced features.

*Simple to start with..*

```
var cache = CacheFactory.Build<string>(
    p => p.WithSystemRuntimeCacheHandle());
```

*Easy to use...*

```
cache.AddOrUpdate("key", "region", "value", _ => "update value");
cache.Expire("key", "region", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var val = cache.Get("key", "region");
var item = cache.GetCacheItem("key", "region");
cache.Put("key", "put value");
```